# how to print MultipleObjectsReturned in django

Tags: python, django

i have different posts in my cat(category) i am getting catid from url & trying to print it.

but getting this error now.

```
MultipleObjectsReturned
```

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('cat/<int:post_cat>/', views.cat, name='cat'),
]
```

(My Table Name is Post)

```
def cat(request, post_cat):
    if request.method =="GET":
        cats =  get_object_or_404(Post, cat=post_cat)
        return render(request, 'ads/cat.html',{'detail':cats})
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: What's the name of the field in your model ? If it's cat, you should do `get_object_or_404(Post, cat=post_cat)` and not the contrary

Comment: @Lotram its cat, & also tried this but not working, getting this error "get() returned more than one Post -- it returned 13!
"

Comment: It means you have more than one Post object with cat = 13, the get method from the ORM is supposed to return exactly one object. If you want to get all the objects, you can use the `filter` method : `Post.objects.filter(cat=post_cat)`

Comment: oh its working thanks

Comment: You should read more about the [model layer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/) in Django to understand how the ORM works

Comment: yeah u r right thanks for the link

Comment: You're welcome.